# compiler does not recognize System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer c#

Tags: c#, xmlserializer, datacontractserializer, datacontract

I try to use `System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer`, but I get a compiler error:

> "The type or namespace 'DataContractSerializer' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Runtime.Serialization' "

What could be causing this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add reference to System.Runtime.Serialization assembly in your project.

Comment: I allready do it. Still not workind and it doesn`t recogonize the System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer, it means it recognize only some methods of System.Runtime.Serialization and some not.

Comment: I am not talking about using statments....Go to your project ->Right click references->select add reference.....Here you have to add reference to System.Runtime.Serialization dll which you will find in assemblies tab

Comment: Refer this link to understand how to add references in Visual studio....https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7314433t(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: It`s working now according to your last recomendation. Thanks a lot!